# Extract repeating regex to util class in Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a contract definition, here is a part of it:

```
...
queryParameters {
  parameter('postcode': $(
    client(ukPostcode()),
    server('PH16 5RU')
  )
...
```

on top of my `contract.groovy` I have:

```
static String ukPostcode() {
    return Pattern.compile("(?i)^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Za-z]? ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}\$(?-i)").pattern()
}
```

This worked fine until I started to need `ukPostcode()` in another contract file in the same project. I tried:

- creating something like a class `CustomPatterns` with a static method in `CustomPatterns.groovy` in the same folder where contracts are and importing it
- creating same class under `src/main/groovy`, `src/main/java`, `src/test/groovy`, `src/main/groovy` etc.

Contract plugin doesn't seem to see the class in any of those locations.

Is there a correct way to share some method (or a constant) between the contract files?

EDIT: this is a single module project and making it multimodule just for the sake of solving this problem is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is described in the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_extending_the_dsl

It's enough to create a separate jar with the utility functions and then reuse it in the plugin classpath on the producer side and on the consuner side in the dependencies themselves.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the docs before posting this question. 

Creating a separate jar in this project is problematic, as this is a single module project, and introducing a separate module just to share a regex or two looks like an overkill and probably will not be very welcomed by the team. 

I was hoping that there is some middle ground between having the util function in same file where the contract is and having it in the entirely separate module.